# npm-install: Why is there a difference between a "<name>" and a "git-repo-url" package installation for the code?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

**Goal:**
I want to install a special commit of a package.

**Problem:** After installing a package using a GitHub-Url, the code in the node_module folder was significantly different from a normal installation. (This caused webpack to generate error messages, which was not the case with a normal installation.)

**Question:** Is there any way that the code from GitHub is created and perform in the same way (e.g., structure and layout) as after a normal installation?

**Test scenario:**

Normal installation:

```
npm install jquery
```

GitHub installation:

```
npm install git+https://git@github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

**results:**

+.github

+src

...

package.json

[detailed results with github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWgIh.png)

+dist

+external

+src

...

package.json

[detailed results without github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqcUp.png)

Comment: The GitHub url is the source, the other is the package registered on npm.

Comment: If you really want to grab their code from its current state on Github, have you tried one of their `-stable` branches instead of `master`? e.g., `git+https://git@github.com/jquery/jquery.git#3.x-stable`

Comment: Or, since you want a specific commit, you need to put the commit's SHA after the `#`. If the state of that commit is not usable by NPM, then I'm not sure what you can do. It sound like you might not really want that commit, since that commit isn't usable in an NPM (or Webpack?) context. (Maybe you need to change some Webpack configs?) There's nothing special about NPM versus Github -- they're just two different places for hosting code, and the code that the jQuery organization has hosted at each place happens to be structured differently.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for your answer! And sorry for the late response :/.  My understanding so far was that an "npm install" will organize the required version via the specified repository (usually GitHub) on the npmjs website. Now if I understand you correctly, npmjs uses its own directory with data that is completely separate from GitHub. This allows "PACKAGE 7.1.2" to be released, for example, with a production version hosted on npmjs and a development version hosted on GitHub, so that the same version of a package can exist on different platforms in different forms. Have I got that right? :)

Comment: Right, GitHub and NPM have no relationship to each other. A developer can upload completely different (or only mildly different, or identical) code to each service.